# installing Apache 2 on OpenSuse 12.1: How to treat the userid?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, opensuse

I have OpenSUSE 12.1 installed. I tried a lot to get a LAMP installation working. I  set it up with YAST - (with the scheme-installations).

question 1: How to get it working?
question 2: How to configure the apache?
question 3: How can I set up apache2 in `~/public_html`?

I always believed that by default, in openSUSE, the web server runs in the following directory: `~/public_html`

But unfortunately - I installed and the path I afterwards used was the following one... :

```
/srv/www/
```

Question 4: What is wrong there?

Once I have installed like this way and had terrible problems to write to the folders Guess that the **userid** we use just matters. This leads to the question: How should I install the Apache so I won't have problems with permissions?

I read something about mod_userdir but don't understand it much: is it needed?

Comment: Did you follow [these directions](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Linux_Apache_MySQL_PHP) (including the right Apache/httpd package)? Your problem can also be fixed by manually changing the Apache configs. Also, your question is written in a really confusing manner, and your title does not match the question/problem you actually describe.

Comment: many thx for the answer - will follow the instructions later  the day. And i will learn to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is mod_userdir apache module. you can read more about the set up and configuration on the following link.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html

Also you might want to give this a bit of read:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html

Comment: hello deaar gyre -  many thanks for your answer  and hints. greetings